# Mutiple PK's in where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

In my table I have (LocID) which is my PK and I am trying to narrow it down to specific 4, however when I run the query below I get only one answer. What needs to be fixed in this query?

```
-- second we find out the name of the locations 

select name from location where locid = 524 and 512 and 505 and 506 ;
```

Comment: You can replace AND with OR if you want to check either one of those conditions to be true.

Comment: You can update your query with in condition like : where locid in (524,512,505,506).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you intended to write would be better expressed using `WHERE IN`:

```
select name from location where locid = in (524, 512, 505, 506);
```

What is actually happening in your current query is that the `locid` values on the RHS *after* the initial one (`524`) are being interpreted as literal true.  So, your query is identical to this:

```
select name from location where locid = 524 and true and true and true;
```

This of course is just the same as:

```
select name from location where locid = 524;
```

That is, you will only get back records from matching `524`.